# Relative maximum for $f$ at $x=1.2$, what is extrema for $1-f(x)$ and $f(1-x)$

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ has a relative maxima at $x= 1.2$, what can you say about the extrema for $1-f(x)$ and $f(1-x)$?

It's a question in my text review, and it's confusing me. I don't know where to start at all.

Comment: Maybe looking at an example will get you going. For instance, the function given by $f(x) = -(x-1.2)^2$ has a maximum at $x=1.2$. What will the graphs of the functions given by $1-f(x)$ and $f(1-x)$  look like, and where will they have an extremum?

Comment: Is it that the extrema is shifted left by $1$ for $f(1-x)$ and shifts down by $1$ for $1-f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

At a relative maxima, the derivative $f'(x) = 0$. Try to differentiate $1-f(x)$ and $f(1-x)$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Just notice how you get $1-f(x)$ and $f(1-x)$ respectively out of f(x).

1) $1-f(x)$:
1.1) start with f(x) and get -f(x)   , by reflecting along the x-axis.

Analytically: If $M> f(x)>m$ , what can you say when you multiply across by -1?

1.2) You have -f(x), with :

$M'>-f(x)>m'$  What happens when you add 1 across.

2) How about $f(1-x)$, i.e., $f(x) \rightarrow f(1-x)$?

2.1) Find $f(-x)$. Here you reflect along the y-axis. If the maximum of f is at

$x_0$, the max of $f(-x)$ is at$-x_0$. Now try the last step .